# Prove that there are infinite sets of $(a, b, c)$ such that $ab + 1$, $ac + 1$ and $bc + 1$ are perfect square

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that there are infinite sets of integer numbers $(a, b, c)$ that $ab + 1$, $ac + 1$ and $bc + 1$ are perfect square. ($a$, $b$, $c$ are different numbers)

Any hints how to prove the statement? I'm trying to find a way to turn that into a [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)
and then prove it has infinite answers.

Comment: $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ ... right ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit They are integers

Comment: An infinite family with $a = 0$ is easy to find.

Comment: Infinitely **many** sets, not infinite sets.  Each set has cardinality $3$, which is not infinite.

Comment: a good solution can be found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3588)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $a=4n$ , $b=n+1$ and $c=n-1$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
ab+1&=&(2n+1)^2 \\
bc+1&=& n^2 \\
ca+1&=&(2n-1)^2
\end{eqnarray*}

EDIT : for Ovi.

We $ab+1,bc+1,ca+1$ are perfect squares. So there exist $x,y,z$ such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
z^2=ab+1 \\
x^2=bc+1 \\
y^2=ca+1
\end{eqnarray*}
Now subtract these equations pairwise (difference of two squares factorise) and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(z-x)(z+x)=b(a-c) \\
(z-y)(z+y)=a(b-c) \\
(y-x)(y+x)=c(a-b)
\end{eqnarray*}
At this point I totally guessed to equate the factors pairwise (there is no justification for this). Amazingly this gives 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x=\frac{-a+b+c}{2} \\
y=\frac{a-b+c}{2} \\
z=\frac{a+b-c}{2} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute this formula for $z$ into $z^2=ab+1$ & after some algebra, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^2+b^2+c^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=4.\\
a^2-2a(b+c)+(b-c)^2-4=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now consider this as a quadratic in $a$ ... Its disciminant (over 4) needs to be a perfect square ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta=(b+c)^2- \left( (b-c)^2-4 \right) =4bc+4=(2n)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
& the above solution follows.

Comment: +1 Nice solution, but how did you discover it?

Comment: @Ovi ... Please see the edit above. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I wish I could give you another $+1$ $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I got a gold medal recently (for doing nothing) ... I am proper pleased with this!

Answer (score 2):

Let

$a=0$

$b=1$

$c=$ any square minus $1$