# Naturals in AP which produce perfect squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I got this question online:

> Find infinitely many triplets of naturals $a,b,c$ in arithmetibc progression such that $ab+1,bc+1,ac+1$ are perfect squares.

My attempt:

Let $a=b-d,c=b+d$

So

$b^2-bd+1=j^2$

$b^2+bd+1=k^2$

$b^2-d^2+1=l^2$

This gives

$k^2-j^2=2bd$

This implies that $j,k$ cannot be consecutive squares, and also that $bd$ is even.

Also, I get $d=\sqrt{j^2+k^2-2l^2\over2}$. And I tried substituting $j^2+k^2=2b^2+2$, but it doesn't seem this will go anywhere.

Please help.

---

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256701/prove-that-there-are-infinite-sets-of-a-b-c-such-that-ab-1-ac-1-a) is similar, but doesn't have the AP condition.

Comment: Look at the second problem [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3588)

Comment: they used Pell's equation, i see. One thing interesting, not related to this question though, is that why the heck would they give Q3 here? That was the question Terrence Tao couldn't solve in the IMO he won a gold medal in...